# sslv3 alert handshake failure when accessing AWS Lambda Function using Open edX and API Gateway

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, openssl, python-requests, edx

So I have a running image of Bitnami's Open edX Ficus 3.1 release in AWS EC2 with ubuntu 14.04. This platform is coded in python and uses openssl and requests library. The problem at hand is when I'm making an HTTP request through the platform to AWS Lambda function (it's HTTPS secured) I get the following when logging the python error:

```
[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:661)
```

How can I resolve it? I tried updating requests (0.14.2) and openssl (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017) library but it's still the same error.

Comment: pip install requests[security]

Comment: pip install -U pyopenssl pyasn1 ndg-httpsclient

Comment: I tried that, but still have the same problem

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. The problem was that xqueue and edx-platform have their own python versions, so instead of updating the requests library in the VM, you need to find the pip of xqueue and install --update requests library from there